# Reserving physical memory space as early as possible in Linux boot-time

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am trying to find a way to reserve physical memory for a proprietary memory type hardware as early as possible after system boots up (Linux CentOs with Intel Xeon server platform).

I did the following at setup_arch() in arch/x86/kernel/setup.c and it works, but found out that I am not allowed to patch the kernel. The requirement is no BIOS and kernel mod.

```
setup_arch()
{    
  ....
  // Calls a proprietary function that returns custom proprietary memory module's starting address and size. 

  memblock_reserve(mem_start_addr, mem_size);  
  .....
 }
```

I cannot use memmap=xx/xx either at Grub, because the start and size of the device is unknown (it has to be "discovered" by software)

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I've been writing linux kernel/drivers for 20+ and, IMO, the "no patch" requirement is, well, silly ... in this context [specialized hardware].  Okay, so no patch to `setup_arch`, but what about adding a driver/module that is a "built in" (i.e. compiled directly into the kernel--_not_ dynamically loadable). Plenty of modules/drivers are built that way.  If you [still] can't, I seriously question the sanity of the requirement unless there is a _really_ good reason [and I'd love to hear it].

Comment: There is kernel parameter called `mem` which could be used to specify the memory size kernel can use.  You could reserve some phisical memory by giving a smaller `mem`.

Comment: Craig, "driver/module that is a "built in"  is what I also had in mind, but the driver usually will get loaded much later in the boot process. We are required to protect/reserve the hardware memory space before linux touches it, because it may yield undefined behavior in the hardware. In between, kernel boots to the driver, there is a chance that linux does something to that memory space. Is this right?

Comment: @electro Did you ever find an answer to this question? I'm trying to achieve the same thing as you. We have a device that we need explicit control over, and do not want the Linux kernel to be loaded into this memory space at any point in time. What do you recommend?

Answer (score 2):

One idea is to write a custom grub module and set `memmap=xx` using it.
The following is how to do it.

Note that following method only works above CentOS 7 since [CentOS 6.x or below uses grub 0.9x](http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=centos) .
In that case, you may have to modify code of grub 0.9x and replace `/boot/grub/stage1` or `/boot/grub/stage2`

```
$ git clone git://git.savannah.gnu.org/grub.git
$ cd grub
$ git checkout grub-2.02-beta2 # CentOS 7 currently uses grub-2.02-beta
$ vim grub-core/Makefile.core.def # add following row
module = {
    name = my_custom_module;
    common = lib/my_custom_module.c;
};

$ vim grub-core/lib/my_custom_module.c # create following file
#include <grub/dl.h>
#include <grub/env.h>

GRUB_MOD_LICENSE ("GPLv3+");

GRUB_MOD_INIT(my_custom_module){
    // Calls a proprietary function that returns custom proprietary memory module's starting address and size.
    const char *mem_size = "123";
    grub_env_set("my_memsize",mem_size);
}
GRUB_MOD_FINI(my_custom_module){
}
$ ./autogen.sh
$ ./configure
$ make
```

Now you can find that `grub-core/my_custom_module.mod` is created.
so copy it to `/boot/grub2/i386-pc/` (or whatever your `*.mod` file exists)

Edit the grub.conf and add something like

```
insmod my_custom_module
linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.10.el7.x86_64 root=UUID=1a3b5c7d9 ro memmap=${my_memsize}
```

Comment: memmap is usually used like memmap=4G/$2G which means reserving 4G memory at address=2G.  So, do I need to create a string of "4G/$2G" and at the grub.cfg, memmap={string} ? What is the right way to do this?

Comment: @electro I think you can just generate `char *the_string="4G/$2G"` inside GRUB_MOD_INIT and call `grub_env_set("my_memsize",the_string)`.  With that module, `${my_memsize}` in grub.conf will be replaced with `the_string`